# Drupal 7 Subscriptions and Notifications : Adding default subscriptions for an authenticated user for some of the content types

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-7, notifications, subscription

I am trying to configure notifications and subscriptions for my website. I wanted some of the subscriptions for some of the content types to be added by default for every authenticated user which (s)he can alter/remove later using Subscriptions UI. I could not find any option for default subscriptions anywhere, neither was able to figure out from my Google search results.

After installing notifications module, user is able to subscribe to the content type manually and any new post is being notified to user correctly via mail.

So, please suggest a way to perform this, some procedure using current module, or a new module, or some hack to add subscriptions by default for every authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [subscriptions module for Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions), you can set the various "content type subscriptions" for users by default.

Just simply install the module and visit this location to setup defaults:

```
admin/config/system/subscriptions/userdefaults/type
```

[image: screenshot of module config page]